# "Conversion failed when converting date" while inserting CSV data

Tags: python, sql-server, database, csv, pyodbc

I am attempting to insert data into a SQL table from a CSV using the following code:

```
with requests.get(reportURL) as csvfile:
    decoded_content=csvfile.content.decode('utf-8')
    reader = csv.reader(decoded_content.splitlines(), delimiter=',')
    columns = next(reader,None)
    query = "INSERT INTO SQL_TABLE({0}) VALUES ({1})"
    query = query.format('[{0}]'.format('],['.join(columns)),','.join('?'*len(columns)))
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query, columns)
    for data in reader:
        cursor.execute(query, data)
    cursor.commit()
```

However, I am receiving the following error code:

> cursor.execute(query, columns) pyodbc.DataError: ('22007', '[22007]
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Conversion
>   failed when converting date and/or time from character string. (241)
>   (SQLExecDirectW)')

I am wondering if the issue is that the data is coming through as a string instead of date? Date is the first column, so I am not sure if any of the other columns would run into a similar issue.
Columns are as follows:

> Date | Advertiser | Campaign | Ad Group | Impressions

Data Type:

> datetime | varchar | varchar | varchar | bigint

Thank you for the help!

Comment: How is your date represented in your csv data?

Comment: > 9/5/2017 | Advertiser 1 | Campaign 1 | Ad Group 1 | 125

No quotes, just as shown.

Comment: Are the dates `m/d/yyyy`, or are they`d/m/yyyy`?

Comment: `m/d/yyyy`, that is how it appears in the csv and seems to be represented in the sql data.

Comment: In your SQL what if you change `VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)` to `VALUES (CONVERT(datetime, ?, 101), ?, ?, ?)` ?

Comment: I was hoping to keep the variable length with `'?'*len(columns)` in there as there are actually about 50 more columns

Comment: Another alternative to try inside your loop before `cursor.execute`:  `data[0] = datetime.datetime.strptime(data[0], '%m/%d/%Y').isoformat()`.  This should force the date string into an unambiguous literal.  Don't forget to `import datetime` at the top.

Answer (score 1):

```python
cursor.execute(query, columns)
```

You are trying to execute the INSERT statement using the column *names* as data. SQL Server is complaining because you are trying to insert the value 'Date' into a `datetime` column. Removing that statement should make the problem go away.

Comment: I think you are correct there! But if its not one problem its another. Now I'm getting **Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint. (8114) (SQLExecDirectW)')**

Comment: @Jamesdabeard:  `try: cursor.execute(query, data)` then `except: print(data)` and also inside the except clause do a bare `raise` to reraise the exception.  Then you will see what line of data it's complaining about.  While you're at it you may as well `print(query)` to make sure the query is what you think it is.

Comment: When I print I see the data coming through in quotes: '112', '0', '0.414', etc. which is maybe the issue?

Comment: @Jamesdabeard - The quotes themselves are not necessarily a problem, but if you are seeing '0.414' for the [Impressions] column then that *is* a problem because 0.414 cannot be stored in a `bigint` column.

Comment: Yes! all is fixed! Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if its still relevant, but i had this error when trying to filter database by date from specific timestamp.
i found that the problem was the data format of the reference point, something like this:'2020-07-26 12:07:22.263000'

the solution was taking the str(my date)[:19] to remove the access data after the seconds

Comment: Sure, for example the datetime.now() will give a date format like this "datetime.datetime(2021,2,25,22,9,41,879400)", and the string for it will be "2021-2-25 22:11:41.879400" and the datetime.timestamp of it will look like 1614284051.277761, float format. so you can take the datetime.timestamp(datetime.now()) and force it to int, receiving 1614284051, and then create datetime.fromtimestamp() of the int timestamp. or use the str format and select the first 19 chars.